# round decimals in ignite ui

Tags: infragistics, ignite-ui

I have an Ignite editable column with  dataType: "number" and format: "0.000" and editor options with maxDecimals set to 3.
However when I enter value as suppose 3.4537 it gets truncated to 3.453 rather than rounding off. I believe this has been fixed in version 17.2 using roundDecimals, however I am on 16.2. Is there an alternate solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

The [roundDecimal](https://www.igniteui.com/help/api/2017.1/ui.ignumericeditor#options:roundDecimals) option is introduced in the Ignite UI product, version 17.1 and above, and there isn't a proper way to do it 16.2. [Here](https://github.com/IgniteUI/ignite-ui/issues/626) is the pull request that is implementing it. Of course we can think of some workaround, but I will not recommend this. Having in mind that editors are one of those controls that are open-source, you can use 17.1 or 17.2 version. Is it possible for you to update the product and what are your concerns about it?